# Embeddings of Complete Graphs and Their Topology

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

Following standard notations, we use $K_n$ to denote a complete graph with n vertices. We know that $K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4$ are planar graphs and a natural notion of vertex, edge, and face can be visualized easily. However, for all $n>4$, $K_n$ is not planar. So my question is: for arbitrary values of $n$, can we analytically find the minimal genus $g$ for which an embedding of $K_n$ on a two dimensional surface exists? If so, is there a systematic way to construct the minimal embedding? How many minimal embeddings are there?

P.S. I did some searches on google but did not find any satisfactory results. So I feel like I might be missing some trivial observation that prevents the existence of such embeddings. If so, please help me out!

Answer (score 5):

[The complete graph $K_n$ has genus $\left\lceil\frac{(n-3)(n-4)}{12}\right\rceil$ for $n\ge3$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphGenus.html).